# Why does getDay return incorrect values? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I tried to get the day of a week with the `getDay()` function of the `Date` object in Javascript. 
In theory it works fine, but sometimes there is a delay in the output, so if the function should return a "4", it returns a "1".

E.g.

```
var date= new Date("2009","04","30");
alert(date.getDay()); // the function returns 6, should return 4

var date= new Date("2009","05","01");
alert(date.getDay()); // the function returns 1, should return 5
```

I really don't know why this happens. This example comes from IE8. FF 3 behaves similar, but returns different values. The first one is 7, not 4. The second one is just like in IE8.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the month number is zero based, not one based.

`new Date("2009","04","30")` creates a `Date` object for the 30th of **may**, not the 30th of april.

(The reason why it's zero based is probably historic, i.e. it behaves the same as some method in a different system way back in time...)

Comment: I don't care what the reason is, it's not good enough. Zero-based months are STUPID. But we're stuck with them...sigh....

Comment: Well, not all languages... The DateTime(int,int,int) constructor in .NET uses a one based month number.

Comment: Agree, the date APIs is not consistent at all. Months go from 0 to 11, days from 1 to 31 and a method like getDay returns a number between 0 to 6 and 0 means Sunday...

Comment: Bruce McKinney (author of Hardcore Visual Basic) said enforcing zero-based arrays in high-level languages is idiotic.