# why javascript getDate not starting from 0

Tags: javascript

[Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) is an integer number, between 0 and 6
[Date.prototype.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) also an integer number, between 0 and 11
then why [Date.prototype.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) is the only function that between 1 and 31? why didn't it starts from 0 ?

Comment: You should really ask MDN why ;)

Comment: @WaisKamal — Why? MDN just documents the language, it doesn't design it.

Comment: "ruin the standard to make things easier", thanks @chazsolo

Answer (score -2):

Because if you look at a calendar you'll notice that the first day of any month is 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Also very related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687521/javascript-date-method-inconsistency-getdate-vs-getmonth