# javascript getDay returns wrong number

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does getDay return incorrect values? (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834757/why-does-getday-return-incorrect-values-javascript)

I have the following code in javaScript

```
var cellDate = new Date('2012', '4', '13');
x.innerHTML=cellDate.getDay();
```

the getDay method instead of returning 5 it returns 0. I am doing any mistake? Here is the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/LPEXj/

Comment: Date('2012', '4', '13');, should be interpretted as Date(Year, Month, Day). Which means it is Friday on 2012 april 13th. So the getDay should return 5.

Comment: Yes but months are zero based so you're asking for May 13th which is a Sunday. Read up on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months are 0-based. 2012 May 13th will be Sunday.

Answer (score 5):

```
var cellDate = new Date('2012', '3', '13');
x.innerHTML=cellDate.getDay();
```

Date months are zero indexed, so actually April would be 3.